# How to bind up and down arrow key to enable navigating through table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm displaying search results with a table. Each result has a button for user to click on to show the full detail of it. That's working well.

What I also want is to make it possible to navigat the search results by using keyboard's up and down arrow.

Now, user have to click on the `Select` button or tab to the button and press `space bar`.

I suppose I can trap the keyup and down event and then find the previous or next one I need to select and then set it, but it sounds like a lot of work. I wonder if there's a better way to do it?

**javascript**

```
var myModel = new function() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedResult = ko.observable(new MyObj());
    self.searchResults = ko.observableArray();
    self.navUpDown = function (item, evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 38) { // up
            var id = item.ID();
            // find previous one and set selectedResult
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 40) { // down
            var id = item.ID();
            // find next one and set selectedResult
        }
    };
};
```

**html**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>table header 1</th>
            <th>table header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: searchResults">
        <tr data-bind="css: { 'btn-info': $parent.selectedResult() == $data }, event: { keyup: $parent.navUpDown } ">
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-small" data-bind="click: $parent.selectResult">Select</button>
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: data1"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: data2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Finding the previous and next one shouldn't be hard at all.  something like $(this).nextSibling() & $(this).prevSibling() should do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
var myModel = new function () {
        var self = this;
        self.selectResult = function (item) {
            self.selectedResult(item);
        };
        self.selectedResult = ko.observable();
        self.searchResults = ko.observableArray([{
            data1: "1",
            data2: "2"
        }, {
            data1: "2",
            data2: "2"
        }, {
            data1: "3",
            data2: "2"
        }]);


        self.selectPrevious = function () {
            var index = self.searchResults().indexOf(self.selectedResult()) - 1;
            if (index < 0) index = 0;
            self.selectedResult(self.searchResults()[index]);
        };

        self.selectNext = function () {
            var index = self.searchResults().indexOf(self.selectedResult()) + 1;
            if (index >= self.searchResults().length) index = self.searchResults().length - 1;
            self.selectedResult(self.searchResults()[index]);
        };


    };
ko.applyBindings(myModel);

$(window).keyup(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
        myModel.selectPrevious();
    } else if (evt.keyCode == 40) {
        myModel.selectNext();
    }
});
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzvDA/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: When the search result gets long, the scroll bar shows up, but the up/down arrow doesn't move the scroll bar.

Comment: Found out that i just need to set focus to the row or elements in the row to make it scroll automatically.

Comment: although this solution may work, this is NOT related to knockout

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not that hard to find `next` and `prev`

For example

```
$(window).keyup(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 38) { // up
       $('tbody tr:not(:first).selected').removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected')
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 40) { // down
       $('tbody tr:not(:last).selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected')
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/MAzm7/2/)

Comment: I don't need to handle the css because ko.js does it for me.